Propogation of errors on syndrome qubits to data qubits in the surface code
This might be a simple thing, but I couldn't find much on it in the usual sources, like Surface codes: Towards practical large-scale quantum computation. They talk about erros on syndrome qubits, but they only seem to mention errors in the measurement process. But take for example a Z stabiliser on 4 qubits, like the central one below.

Shouldn't a Z error before the CNOT gates, so a hook error, propogate to all 4 of the data qubits, and as such perform $Z_{L}$, so a logical error? Now maybe the assumption is that you can always rapidly initialise the syndrome qubits into the ground state and correlate them with the data qubits. But if that isn't the case, how are such hook errors dealt with? The surface code is meant to be fault tolerant, so I am assuming that encoding of the syndrome measurement circuits with a fault tolerant technique isn't the approach here.
I expect what I am probabaly overlooking is that the number of errors that can occurr from this is always 4, so with an appropriately large surface, this wouldn't result in a logical error. However, I am not sure if that is the case, and since it would still be undetected with a round of syndrome measurements, I can't see how it wouldn't still affect the code.


Shouldn't a Z error before the CNOT gates, so a hook error, propogate to all 4 of the data qubits, and as such perform $_$
, so a logical error?

The error you're describing is a stabilizer of the code. A stabilizer acts as identity on an encoded state.

But if that isn't the case, how are such hook errors dealt with?

Any combination of $d$ hook errors propagates to a correctable error. A single hook error propagates to at most a weight two error on the data qubits.  Although $d$ hook errors can thus propagate to $2d$ errors on data qubits, the $2d$ errors are still correctable. See Low-distance Surface Codes under Realistic Quantum Noise.
It may seem like a hook error can propagate to a weight 3 or weight 4 error on data qubits, but if you multiply this weight 3 or weight 4 error with a specific stabilizer this will result in a weight 0 or weight 1 error.

Ah I see what I've done, I've looked at the creation of logical qubits by removing the stabilizer from the code, and equated the operation you get from the error propogation to that logical operation. However, if it was an x error instead, this wouldn't be a stabilizer, this would be an error, but correctable as the parity of the measurement is flipped, and the error wouldn't commutate with the Z stabilizers, yes?

I don't understand the error you're describing. Where in the circuit does it occur?

If it's an X error on the auxiliary qubit occuring in a Z-stabilizer readout circuit this indeed just flips the binary measurement result. It wouldn't spread to data qubits.

Disregard that, I was looking at the wrong circuit, it was the X stabiliser, and of course this would again just give a stabilizer.

Could I ask, in the case of the Z stabiliser above, if a hook error propogates to a weight 3 error, how would stabilizer measurements result in a weight 1 error? If it's multiplication by multiple stabilisers, this makes sense, as eventually you could equate it to just a single error. But I can't see how you would do so with just only a single stabiliser multiplication. Although it's easily seen why this would still be detectable as it doesn't commute with the X-stabilisers now

In a Z stabilizer readout circuit, a Z error propagates to data qubits. If a Z error occurs after the first (out of 4) CNOTs this propagates to a weight 3 error. If you multiply this weight 3 error with the stabilizer that is being measured using the readout circuit, you find a weight 1 error.

Ok yeah that makes perfect sense. I don't know why I keep forgetting about the stabilizer being measured :/
